# Mixing Problem with rate in and out

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Tank $100$ gal with $0.05$ lb of salt for each gal of water.
Pure water in at $3$ gal/min.
Water out at $2$ gal/min.
Salt content when $130$ gal of water?

What I have:

Start volume will increase by $1$ gal a min so we have

$$V(t) = 100 + t $$

Rate of salt will be leaving at an unknown amount at a time, giving

$$dS/dt = -2S/(100+t)$$

Linear and homogenous gives

$$S(t) = A(100 + t)^3$$

Salt at time zero was given giving

$$S(0) = 100 \cdot 0.05 = 5$$

Plugging into $$S(t)$$ gives

$$A = 5 \cdot 10^-6$$

Using $S(t)$ with values

$$S(t) = 5\cdot10^-6 \cdot (130)^3$$ gives an outrageous number.

Am I completely off at solving this problem?

Comment: What does your original question ask for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formulation of the equation is correct, but your solution to it is not.  The solution is $S = \frac{c}{(t+100)^2}$.  Knowing the value of $S(0)=5$ tells you that $S=\frac{5 \times 100^2}{(t+100)^2}$.  Since the volume is 130 gallons when t=30, the total salt at $t=30$ is $S(30)=\frac{5 \times 100^2}{130^2}$, which is quite reasonable.